# Suppressing __add__ when __radd__ is defined

Tags: python

I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return 'Foo.__add__ called'


class Bar(str):
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return 'Bar.__radd__ called'
```

As you can see, I have `Foo` implementing `__add__` and `Bar` implementing `__radd__`.

I can create objects of these classes and add them, because the magic methods are defined.

```
f = Foo('foo')
b = Bar('bar')
```

However, adding them produces this:

```
In [390]: f + b
Out[390]: 'Foo.__add__ called'
```

How can I set it so that `Bar.__radd__` method is called in preference to `Foo.__add__`?

Comment: Make `Bar` a subclass of `Foo`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Hey, what do you know. That worked. Nice one. Turn it into an answer? :) (also a little explanation on how that worked would help...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Add an explicit check in `Foo` related to `Bar`.

```
class Foo(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Bar):
            return NotImplemented
        return 'Foo.__add__ called'


class Bar(str):
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return 'Bar.__radd__ called'
```

2. Make `Bar` a subclass of `Foo`.

[From docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

> **Note:** If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s
>   type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the
>   operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s
>   non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override
>   their ancestors’ operations.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) about the `__rstuff__` methods :

> These functions are only called *if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation* and the operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the expression `x - y`, where y is an instance of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`.

So, in your case, `Foo`, the left operand, does have the `__add__` method, thus, it's called immediately. To avoid that, you can `return NotImplemented` from `Foo.__add__` if the other argument is of type `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

As explain in the Python reference documentation in [Datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) section, that the order use by Python to resolve this case:

1. check for `__add__` on the first operand
2. and only if not implemented check for `__radd__` on the second one.

A possibility to resolve your problem (not really beautiful / pythonic) is to check in your `__add__` implementation if `other` implement the `__radd__` method.

For example with:

```
class Foo(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            return other.__radd__(self)
        except NotImplemented:
            pass
        # __radd__ not implement so return __add__ behavior 
        return 'Foo.__add__ called'
```

With result:

```
In [5]: f + b
Out[5]: 'Bar.__radd__ called'
```